# Reading a file that is passed as argument while using optparse

Tags: ruby, optparse

I'm writing a program that requires arguments in order to be run, one of those possible arguments is the option to use a file by passing the program `-f <file>`. I'm not understanding where this is going wrong, I'm attempting to read the file as `ARGV[1]` because it's the second argument given to the program.

However, calling `ARGV[1]` outputs nothing, however if I added two more arguments on top of the flag and file name given, and then call on `ARGV[1]` it will output the last argument given as 1? So for example:

```
ruby testparse.rb -f test.txt
#<= Nothing there
```

But if I did this:

```
ruby testparse.rb -f test.txt test ttest
#<= ttest
```

That puts `ARGV[1]` at the location of `ARGV[3]`? So my questions being:

- Why can't I call onto a file as `ARGV[1]` while passing it through optparse?
- How do I call on the file to be read while using optparse?

Source:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f=FILE', '--file=FILE', 'File it') { |o| options[:file] = o }
end.parse!

if ARGV[1].nil?
  puts "Nothing there"
else
  puts ARGV[1]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`parse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-parse-21) to parse your command line options, OptionParser removes any that it recognises from `ARGV`, leaving any it doesn’t recognise for you to handle as you want.

In your case, since you’ve specified the `-f` option to take one parameter, those two entries are removed from `ARGV`. In your code you store the option in `options[:file]`, so check that instead of `ARGV[1]`.

Comment: I figured it out, to me personally it seems like you should still be able to call it from `ARGV` though, don't you think?